# ffmpeg overlay video on another

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode

I have a very simple question about ffmpeg.

I need to put **video2** on **video1**.

Like this photo : (with margin from top and left)

[image]

**Video2 is 470*470 px**

I need a simple command to do this.

Please tell me how can i get that result?

I've tried  something like this :

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -vf "movie=blur.mp4:loop=200,scale=iw/2:-1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -vf "movie=blur.mp4:loop=200,scale=iw/2:-1[bg];[bg][0]overlay=LEFT:TOP:shortest=1" out.mp4
```

where LEFT and TOP are replaced with the respective margins.